# babel-plugin-transform-remove-console in dev mode?

Tags: react-native

I needed to run `babel-plugin-transform-remove-console` for my dev build. What I did was:

```
npm i babel-plugin-transform-remove-console --save-dev
```

Then in `.babelrc` I changed it to this:

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native"],
  "plugins": ["transform-remove-console"]
}
```

I also tried:

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native"],
  "env": {
    "development,": {
      "plugins": ["transform-remove-console"]
    }
  }
}
```

However console logging is still happening in my dev build. I am on Android.

Does anyone know how to get this to work in dev mode?

Comment: Your logic is correct, i see 2 issues: a) you have forgotten a comma next to "development" word, b) you are installing and then using a different plugin. Since you are installing "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console" this is what you need to specify below, not the "transform-remove-console". Just configured this setup as well under Babel 7.8 in React Native app

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you are using new babel version 7, you need to change this file `babel.config.js` instead of `.babelrc` as the following:

```
module.exports = function override(api) {

  var env = api.cache(() => process.env.NODE_ENV);
  var isProd = api.cache(() => process.env.NODE_ENV === "production");

  if (!isProd) {
    config = {
      plugins: [
        ["transform-remove-console"]
      ],
      presets: ["@babel/preset-flow", "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"]
    };
  }

  return config;
};
```

this should remove the console in the new babel versions

Comment: Don't the new babel versions still also make use of .babelrc?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the version 0.62.x or newer, you can update your `babel.config.js` as follows:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  if (api.env("production")) {
    return {
      "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
      "plugins": [
        "transform-flow-strip-types",
        "transform-remove-console"
      ]
    }
  }

  return {
    "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
    "plugins": [
      "transform-flow-strip-types",
    ]
  }
};
```

PS: make sure to restart bundler with cache reset like this `npm start --reset-cache` and note that this will not prevent logs from redux logger (tested that).

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
{
 "presets": ["react-native"],
 "plugins": ["dev-expression", "babel-plugin-dev-expression"]
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks Danh, why is this though, does remvoe console have it hard coded in itself to only work in production?

Comment: As per given in https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html#using-consolelog-statements, it will remove console logs from production mode, but I tried this its not working at all. Anything missing from my end?

Comment: same issue, any findings?

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = {
    presets: ["@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset"],
     
    env: {
        development: {},
        production: {
            plugins: ["transform-remove-console"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?